# How to install GRUB on a USB drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, usb, grub

I have an installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm a huge security freak, so as an extra layer of security and a fun project to occupy my time, I thought about removing the bootloader from my hard drive and installing one on a spare USB flash drive I have, so that the OS will only boot from the hard drive when the flash drive is inserted.  I want to keep all my data on the hard drive but require the flash drive to be plugged in to boot.  Is this possible, and, if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the Grub superdisk .iso and burn it to the flashdrive with either the "dd" command, or a graphical Windows .iso burner like win32 disk imager. I did the same thing :)

Comment: But how to remove it from hard drive?

Comment: can be found here

Comment: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/

Comment: Do you care if you wipe the whole MBR or just remove grub? Wiping the whole MBR would work and would be easier but will bite you in the future if you lose the USB.

Comment: Sorry idk what MBR is :P

Comment: I just want to make it so its unbootable by itself

Comment: MBR- master boot record. If you delete that partition, the computer will be unable to start by itself. Start by writing the supergrubdisk to a flash drive, and make sure its bootable before you do anything, and then use gparted to delete the partition with the MBR flag. Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.